# redmine - register a new user through API without having admin rights

Tags: json, rest, redmine

In Redmine is possible to register new account using web interface via 
http://redmine/account/register

When *Submit* is performed browser sends a `POST` to `account\register` with this data:

```
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=6XEpkFIoAsXyIvAk3j%xxxxxxxroM3yJm5yV4dLoExNg%3D&user%5Blogin%5D=myuser&user%5Bpassword%5D=password&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=password&user%5Bfirstname%5D=firstname&user%5Blastname%5D=lastname&user%5Bmail%5D=test123%40mydomain.tld&user%5Blanguage%5D=it&commit=Invia
```

In logfile is possible to see:

```
Started POST "/account/register" for 173.102.44.73 at 2017-03-09 15:53:13 +0100

[...]

{
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"long_alphanumeric_string",
    "user"=>{
        "login"=>"mynewuser",
        "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
        "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
        "firstname"=>"myfirstname",
        "lastname"=>"mylastname",
        "mail"=>"test123@mydomain.tld",
        "language"=>"it"
    },
    "commit"=>"Invia"
}
```

Redmine has [Rest API support](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) but I can't find how to register a new user using JSON.

**EDIT**: Is it possible to *create/register* new user via JSON `POST` using http://redmine/users.json as described [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Users) but *Administrators* rights are needed.

Web interface permits account registration for *anonymous* users, is it also possible via Rest API ?

Comment: AFAIK `register` == `create` so [this](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Users#POST) maybe ?

Comment: That was my first attempt but always getting **401 UNAUTHORIZED** led me to believe that was not the right service to call. Also because the web interface seems to call a different RestAPI.

Comment: well you have to be authorized or the rights have to be that anonymous can create users (not that I recommend it) - checkout: [Authentication](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Authentication)

Comment: Self registration is usually activated by default. Account activation is what may needs the intervention of ad admin (there is a setting also for autoactivation).

Comment: you need to use either `HTTP Basic auth` or an `api key` to use (most) of the API *at all* - see the link I provided

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

- create a redmine api-user i.e. `api-user-cancreateusers`
- enable REST API in Administration -> Settings -> Authentication
- generate/get the api-user api-key
- *give the api-user rights to create users*
- put the api-user name and key into your program/service
- profit!

[redmine-auth-doc](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Authentication)

---

Edit:

> give the api-user rights to create users

as hinted in the comment - it seems there is no such thing. the only way seems to give the api user admin rights (*shudder*)

alternatively fetch the account/register page and replay with the provided auth_token

Comment: Can you provide more info about: `give the api-user rights to create users`